# Sort an array of 0s, 1s and 2s (Further optimization)

Tags: c#, algorithm

Below is a very simple code which **sorts** **array** of **0s, 1s and 2s**. I believe it's **time complexity** is **O(N)**, right? How can this algo be further **improved** to bring down time complexity to **O(logN)** or so?

```
//Input:  0 2 1 2 0
//Output: 0 0 1 2 2
    public static int[] SortArray012(int[] array)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> result = new Dictionary<int, int>(3);
            int[] sortedResult = new int[array.Length];
            int i = 0;

            foreach(int no in array)
            {
                if (result.ContainsKey(no))
                    result[no]++;
                else
                    result.Add(no, 1);
            }

            for (; i < result[0]; i++)
                sortedResult[i] = 0;
            for (; i < result[0] + result[1]; i++)
                sortedResult[i] = 1;
            for (; i < result[0] + result[1] + result[2]; i++)
                sortedResult[i] = 2;

            return sortedResult;
        }
```

Comment: Please tell us what this method is supposed to be doing.  Better yet, show us a sample input array, and also the output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about optimizing working code It is better suited for [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: At the very least you need to look at each value of the array, this is an example of counting sort. I believe you can't get better than `O(N)`

Comment: So the code does a fairly expensive count of 0's, 1's and 2's using a dictionary and only expecting the values to fall within the range of an `int`. Then it populates an array by counting up to the counts in the dictionary whilst dropping digits along the way. While I doubt you can avoid inspecting each input value you can certainly count them more efficiently, e.g. `counts[ digit ]++` for each input digit. Do you really need to produce an array (of arbitrary length) for the result or could you calculate the value for a given subscript from the three counts more efficiently?

Comment: If an algorithm depends on every element in an input vector of size N, it is impossible to do execute it faster than O(N), because in less time you could not examine every element of the input vector.

Comment: You can do this in-place in O(n) time. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of counting sort. While there is no way to my knowledge to lower the asymptotic complexity you can focus on reducing the constants. For example there is no need to construct a dictionary, an array will do. If we are guaranteed that we will only see 1,2 and 0 then there is no need for the if statement. We can also generate our result with two for loops instead of three

```
int[] test = {1,1,0,2,1,0};
int[] count = {0,0,0};
int[] result = new int[test.Length];
foreach(int no in test){
    count[no]++;    
}
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
foreach(int c in count){
    for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){
        result[k++] = i;    
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop isn't quite correct. It always starts at `result[0]` but instead should continue from where the previous loop ended. Btw, I agree that any solution is at least O(n).

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks for pointing that out, thats what I get for programming so late :)

Comment: Wouldn't two loops make the complexity to be O(n2)?

Comment: No, you can loop k times from 0 to l where k and l are constants and the complexity will be o(1)..

Comment: You can do it in-place in O(n), with O(1) additional memory. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem